# How can I display and excerpt of all pages with a meta_key and meta_value on index.php?

Tags: theme-development, pages

I need to create some pages with a custom field called categoria-pagina so I can display a list of these pages and their excerpt on my theme's index.php. I have already tried the code bellow, but if I use the args it doesn't display anything.

```
<?php
        $args = array(
            'meta_key' => 'categoria-pagina',
            'meta_value' => 'programas'
          );

        $pages = get_pages($args);

        foreach ($pages as $page) {
          echo "<p>$page->post_title</p>";
        }

        wp_reset_postdata();
      ?>
```

[image: Page custom fields]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how to do it with Pages, but with Posts or CPT I use the following list of of args :

```
 <?php $args = array( 
                  'post_type' => 'post', 
                  'post_status' => 'publish', 
                  'meta_key' => 'votes_count', 
                  'orderby' => 'meta_value_num'; 

 $wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );
 ?>
```

What does a `print_r($args)` return for you ?

Comment: Also found out that you need to declare this in your args `'post_type' => 'page'`